# create responsive images with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

For having responsive images i use bootstrap class=img-responsive. The class indeed works perfectly. However It makes image smaller from the beginning. I need to have scale=1, the exact size from psd file. in css i wrote:

```
.img-responsive{
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;

    }
```

In the head I have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But it still doesnt work. Thanks!

Comment: You can add `min-width: 300px` for example to prevent it from being smaller, But that usually means the container has small width - you might need to rethink how you're doing this. Also provide a working demo - your code is not enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The image will have the same width as its container, you'll need to adjust the width of that

Comment: `class=img-responsive` scales the image to fit the container, which you say is working. I'm not sure what effect you expect `initial-scale=1` to have on the images. When you say `the exact size from psd file` it sounds like you want the image to always stay the same resolution not matter what screen size. You are going to have to clarify exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a max-width and min-width. Using these, you can tell the image to be a minimum width at a specific point and a maximum. I would have posted this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep. Sorry, guys.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. I don't use bootstrap, but from what I can see in the CSS he's providing, he is only setting a width. Maximum of which is provided by `display: block;`. He can, however, apply a min-width which will force a minimum width until it reaches a point (if he used a media query). He hasn't provided much code in all fairness

Answer (score 0):

> see its very much clear that image is having width of 100% , but if
>   your image is shrink which means this is because of image container.
>   for example

```
.container {
 width:100%;
}
.img-container {
 width:50%;
}
.img {
width: 100%;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="img" src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dinker/j1rzdsn7/)

And Now if you want to see the real size of image just do this change::

**making image container width as 100%**

```
.img-container {
     width:100%;
    }
```